# Jackson: unable to explicitly indicate target class in polymorphism without providing id?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I'm trying to read a `JSON` using `Jackson`, where the target class is subclass of an abstract that has already properly been annotated.

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClass1.class, name = "sub1"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClass2.class, name = "sub2"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = SubClass3.class, name = "sub3")
})
public abstract class SuperClass {

}

public class SubClass1 extends SuperClass {}
public class SubClass2 extends SuperClass {}
public class SubClass3 extends SuperClass {}
```

This works all fine and dandy when I'm reading something like:

```
objectMapper.readValue("{\"type\":\"sub1\"}", SuperClass.class);
```

This creates a new `SubClass1` as expected.

However, when I try to explicitly provide the intended class (and omit the type from the `JSON`:

```
objectMapper.readValue("{}", SubClass1.class);
```

I get an exception:

> Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'type' that is to contain type id  (for class com.test.SubClass1)
>    at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]

Why do I still need to provide the type when I am explicitly providing it as the second parameter? As a side note if I do provide the (correct) type, it works, but if I provide a wrong type, say...

```
objectMapper.readValue("{\"type\":\"sub2\", SubClass1.class);
```

> Class com.test.SubClass2 is not assignable to com.test.SubClass1

Which makes sense, but again why do I need to provide the type value (when clearly it expects only one specific value)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register new `DeserializationProblemHandler` and return `baseType`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializationProblemHandler;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jsontype.TypeIdResolver;
import java.io.IOException;

public class JsonApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    objectMapper.addHandler(
        new DeserializationProblemHandler() {
          @Override
          public JavaType handleMissingTypeId(DeserializationContext ctxt, JavaType baseType, TypeIdResolver idResolver, String failureMsg) {
            return baseType;
          }
        });

    System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue("{}", SubClass1.class));
    System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue("{}", SubClass2.class));
    System.out.println(objectMapper.readValue("{}", SubClass3.class));
  }
}
```

Above code will print 3 objects with given types.

Comment: Wow, neat. Thank you I will try that out!